Successful pointer association with data object without target attribute through subroutine
Recently I noticed that it is possible to associate a pointer with a data object without the target attribute through the use of a subroutine. I tested this with a 4x4 array arr by associating ptr_to_arr => arr and then by performing subtraction arr-ptr_to_arr, which yielded 0.0 everywhere.
Because only the dummy argument of subroutine assign_ptr and not the actual argument has the target attribute, I expected the pointer to become disassociated outside the subroutine's scope. However it remains associated.
Can someone say whether this conforms to the Fortran standard or whether this is a bug? I am using GCC 11.4.0.
! ---------------------------
! MODULE CONTAINING PROCEDURE
! ---------------------------
module assign_ptr_mod

  implicit none
  
  contains

  subroutine assign_ptr (arr, ptr)

    implicit none

    real, dimension (:, :), target, intent (in) :: arr
    real, dimension (:, :), pointer, intent (out) :: ptr

    ptr => arr

  end subroutine assign_ptr

end module assign_ptr_mod



! -------------
! BEGIN PROGRAM
! -------------
program main

  use assign_ptr_mod, only : assign_ptr

  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: nx = 4, ny = 4
  integer :: j
  real, dimension (:, :), allocatable :: arr
  real, dimension (:, :), pointer :: ptr_to_arr

  ! Populate array with random numbers
  allocate (arr(nx, ny))
  call random_number (arr)
  call assign_ptr (arr, ptr_to_arr)

  print *, '-------------------------'
  print *, 'Is ptr_to_arr associated?'
  print *, '-------------------------'
  print *, 'Association status is ', associated (ptr_to_arr)
  print *

  print *, '------------------------------------------------'
  print *, 'INITIAL ARRAY VALUES BY RANDOM NUMBER GENERATOR'
  print *, '------------------------------------------------'
  call printer ()

  ! Repopulate array with random numbers
  call random_number (arr)

  print *, '------------------------------------------------'
  print *, 'UPDATED ARRAY VALUES BY RANDOM NUMBER GENERATOR'
  print *, '------------------------------------------------'
  call printer ()

  contains

  subroutine printer

    implicit none

    print *, 'array values are'
    print *
  
    do j = ny, 1, -1
      print *, arr(:, j)
    end do
    print *
  
    print *, 'ptr values are'
    print *
  
    do j = ny, 1, -1
      print *, ptr_to_arr(:, j)
    end do
    print *
  
    print *, 'substract ptr values from arr (should yield zero)'
    print *
  
    do j = ny, 1, -1
      print *, arr(:, j) - ptr_to_arr(:, j)
    end do
    print *

  end subroutine printer

end program main


Welcome to Fortran.

The code is nonconforming Fortran.  Any result you find is correct or incorrect.  See Fortran 2023 19.5.2.5(6).

To be explicit: the pointer becomes of undefined association status, it doesn't remain associated. If a pointer's association status is undefined, you cannot inquire of its association.

Thanks for reaffirming my suspicions.

This is misleading, because most of time such code will work. Nonetheless it is non-conformant and therefore not guaranteed to work.

@PierU That is exactly the point I am getting at - the code works in this case, for my machine today, although it should not and maybe won't work tomorrow. It is a pitfall.

A tip for all users, who might read this later: If a questionable code like the one posted here works, check the Fortran standard directly. I checked my books on Fortran first and didn't find a direct answer.

Another tip for other readers: use as many tools for error detection as possible. Unfortunately, though, if you use pointers, it's ultimately your responsibility to know and follow the rules.

@AndrisR. it's wrong to say that the code should not work. This is a non-conformant code, which results in an undefined behavior. "undefined" can be anything: runtime crash, run with wrong results, start WWIII, or work with correct results... Ideally one would want the compiler to catch all possible coding mistakes, but in practice this is impossible.

Some languages are designed with "safety first" in mind (e.g. Ada), such that (among other things) most errors (if not all) can be detected at compile time. But this is generally at the expense of less flexibility in the language. So this is a trade-off between safety and flexibility.
